# How to swap even and odd digits in a decimal number?

Tags: c

For example:
1: 123456 should be converted to 214365
2: 12345 should be converted to 103254

Comment: I suggest implementing your algorithm, (whatever it is exactly), with some code.

Comment: Back in the day, there was a really great way to do this in 370 Assembler. Just saying.

Comment: The OP seems to have lost all interest. The topic is irrelevant in general; maybe delete the question?

Comment: @eznme I don't know why you said the topic is irrelevant. Can you please tell me why should i delete the question.

Comment: And i was wondering whether is there a method which works efficiently than the modulo thing.

Comment: @user3096415 you seemed to have lost interest for more than 1 hour no answers to the comments, no votes and especially no improvement to your question.

Comment: @eznme Oh sorry for that i was busy in some other work couldn't get into this.

Comment: And please tell me why is this irrelevant??.

Comment: @user3096415 no problem. it is only irrelevant to other users because it has no practical purpose to swap digits other than to practice programming.

Comment: @eznme oh fine, got it. I thought something else.

Comment: And can you tell me applications of swapping even and odd bits in a binary number

Answer (score 1):

```
int32_t conv(int32_t n){
    char buff[16], *p = &buff[1];
    int i, v = n < 0 ? -n : n;

    sprintf(p, "%010d", v);
    for(i=0;i<5;++i,++p){
        char c;
        c = *p;
        *p = p[1];
        *(++p) = c;
    }
    buff[0] = (n < 0) ? '-' : ' ';
    return atoi(buff);
}
```

---

```
size_t conv(size_t n){
    size_t q, r, wk, mul=1, ret = 0;
    for(;n;n/=100, mul*=100){
        wk = n % 100;
        r = wk % 10;
        q = wk / 10;
        ret += (r * 10 + q)*mul;
    }
    return ret;
}
```

,

Comment: this even handles negative numbers. it makes it more complicated but more general.

Comment: whoever downvoted: yes we know you can do this with math rather than strings; please post your math version, let's see how easy to comprehend it is.

Comment: @eznme Um, I didn't downvote. Conversely, I just noticed this answer and upvoted it. (Don't accuse me of things I haven't done.)

Answer (score 0):

First to clarify: there's a difference between an integer and the decimal representation of that integer in a string. You want the second.

As H2CO3 points out you can do this on your own using modulo's: decompose your number into the decimal base, do the swaps then recompose the number (only mul/add).

Here's another way:

- Create a string from your integer using malloc and sprintf.
- Loop through the string and do the swapping of characters
- print that string or if you want convert it back to an integer with atoi

Comment: That's completely unnecessary. This is a math problem, and one should use maths to solve it. Extracting a digit is easily done using modulus and division; re-composing a number with the aforementioned digits is achieved by multiplication by powers of ten and addition.

Comment: @H2CO3 Yes, but the OP is a beginner. YOU tell him about modulo.

Comment: o.O Modulo is an elementary maths operation. It has nothing to do with OP being a beginner in programming.

Comment: @H2CO3 I dont mean modulo itself but the decomposing and recomposing of the number.